# When i update the data, it makes duplicates same data in the app firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am listing my data with using firebase realtime database in my application. These data are constantly updated.
But when the data is updated ones time in firebase, the second of the same data is formed in my application. Listing data increases by 1 with each update.
I mean;
There is 1 piece of data in firebase realtime database and when that data is updated it continues to appear same data as 2-3-4-5-6.

Here is my code:

```
  mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    trackItems = new ArrayList<Track>();

    adapter = new TracksAdapter(this, trackItems);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            pos = position;
            myListView.setItemChecked(position, true);

        }
    });

    final ValueEventListener trackListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                Track track = dataSnapshot.getValue(Track.class);
                track.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                trackItems.add(0, track);
                myListView.setItemChecked(0, true);
                refreshList();


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            shortWarnToast("Veriler yüklenirken bir hata oluştu.");
        }
    };


    ValueEventListener user_tracksListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            trackItems.clear();
            pos = -1;
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> user_trackChildren = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            for (DataSnapshot track : user_trackChildren) {
                String key = track.getKey();
                mDatabaseReference.child("/tracks/" + key).addValueEventListener(trackListener);
            }
            refreshList();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            shortWarnToast("Veriler yüklenirken bir hata oluştu.");
        }
    };
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `trackItems.clear();` in the first `onDataChange`.

Comment: When I add this, if there are 2 pieces of data, only the most up-to-date data appears. so the last data

Comment: @MustapTR can you explain better what you mean by only 2 pieces of data.  which of the data duplicates

Comment: @samuelochuba For example; I'm listing just 2 data. When I change the data of one of them, 3 data appears on the page. When the data is updated, it looks the duplicate the data.